# Spark EMR Cluster is removing executors when run because they are idle

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, emr, apache-spark-2.0

I have a spark application that was running fine in standalone mode, I'm now trying to get the same application to run on an AWS EMR Cluster but currently it's failing.

The message is one I've not seen before and implies that the workers are not receiving jobs and are being shut down.

```
    **16/11/30 14:45:00 INFO ExecutorAllocationManager: Removing executor 3 because it has been idle for 60 seconds (new desired total will be 7)
16/11/30 14:45:00 INFO YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Requesting to kill executor(s) 2
16/11/30 14:45:00 INFO ExecutorAllocationManager: Removing executor 2 because it has been idle for 60 seconds (new desired total will be 6)
16/11/30 14:45:00 INFO YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Requesting to kill executor(s) 4
16/11/30 14:45:00 INFO ExecutorAllocationManager: Removing executor 4 because it has been idle for 60 seconds (new desired total will be 5)
16/11/30 14:45:01 INFO YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Requesting to kill executor(s) 7
16/11/30 14:45:01 INFO ExecutorAllocationManager: Removing executor 7 because it has been idle for 60 seconds (new desired total will be 4)**
```

The DAG shows the workers initialised, then a collect (one that is relatively small) and then shortly after they all fail.
Dynamic allocation was enabled so there was a thought that perhaps the driver wasn't sending them any tasks and so they timed out - to prove the theory I spun up another cluster without dynamic allocation and the same thing happened.

The master is set to yarn.

Any help is massively appreciated, thanks.

```
    16/11/30 14:49:16 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Removal of executor 21 requested
16/11/30 14:49:16 INFO YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnDriverEndpoint: Asked to remove non-existent executor 21
16/11/30 14:49:16 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Trying to remove executor 21 from BlockManagerMaster.
16/11/30 14:49:24 WARN YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnSchedulerEndpoint: Container marked as failed: container_1480517110174_0001_01_000049 on host: ip-10-138-114-125.ec2.internal. Exit status: 1. Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1480517110174_0001_01_000049
Exit code: 1
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=1: 
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:545)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:456)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:722)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

My step is quite simple - `spark-submit --deploy-mode client --master yarn --class Run app.jar`

Comment: Also experiencing the same.

Comment: This SO post ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44183527/why-would-spark-executors-be-removed-with-executorallocationmanager-request-t)) seems related

Comment: Did you ever solve this?  I'm seeing the same thing trying to launch an EMR spark job from airflow.