# Why would Spark executors be removed (with "ExecutorAllocationManager: Request to remove executorIds" in the logs)?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn

Im trying to execute a spark job in an AWS cluster of 6 c4.2xlarge nodes  and I don't know why Spark is killing the executors...
Any help will be appreciated

Here the spark submit command:

```
. /usr/bin/spark-submit --packages="com.databricks:spark-avro_2.11:3.2.0" --jars RedshiftJDBC42-1.2.1.1001.jar --deploy-mode client --master yarn --num-executors 12 --executor-cores 3 --executor-memory 7G --driver-memory 7g --py-files dependencies.zip iface_extractions.py 2016-10-01 > output.log
```

At line this line starts to remove executors

```
17/05/25 14:42:50 INFO ExecutorAllocationManager: Request to remove executorIds: 5, 3
```

Output spark-submit log:

```
Ivy Default Cache set to: /home/hadoop/.ivy2/cache
The jars for the packages stored in: /home/hadoop/.ivy2/jars
:: loading settings :: url = jar:file:/usr/lib/spark/jars/ivy-2.4.0.jar!/org/apache/ivy/core/settings/ivysettings.xml
com.databricks#spark-avro_2.11 added as a dependency
:: resolving dependencies :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent;1.0
    confs: [default]
    found com.databricks#spark-avro_2.11;3.2.0 in central
    found org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.7.5 in central
    found org.apache.avro#avro;1.7.6 in central
    found org.codehaus.jackson#jackson-core-asl;1.9.13 in central
    found org.codehaus.jackson#jackson-mapper-asl;1.9.13 in central
    found com.thoughtworks.paranamer#paranamer;2.3 in central
    found org.xerial.snappy#snappy-java;1.0.5 in central
    found org.apache.commons#commons-compress;1.4.1 in central
    found org.tukaani#xz;1.0 in central
:: resolution report :: resolve 284ms :: artifacts dl 8ms
    :: modules in use:
    com.databricks#spark-avro_2.11;3.2.0 from central in [default]
    com.thoughtworks.paranamer#paranamer;2.3 from central in [default]
    org.apache.avro#avro;1.7.6 from central in [default]
    org.apache.commons#commons-compress;1.4.1 from central in [default]
    org.codehaus.jackson#jackson-core-asl;1.9.13 from central in [default]
    org.codehaus.jackson#jackson-mapper-asl;1.9.13 from central in [default]
    org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.7.5 from central in [default]
    org.tukaani#xz;1.0 from central in [default]
    org.xerial.snappy#snappy-java;1.0.5 from central in [default]
    :: evicted modules:
    org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.6.4 by [org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.7.5] in [default]
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    |                  |            modules            ||   artifacts   |
    |       conf       | number| search|dwnlded|evicted|| number|dwnlded|
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    |      default     |   10  |   0   |   0   |   1   ||   9   |   0   |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
:: retrieving :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent
    confs: [default]
    0 artifacts copied, 9 already retrieved (0kB/8ms)
17/05/25 14:41:37 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 2.1.0
17/05/25 14:41:38 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: hadoop
17/05/25 14:41:38 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: hadoop
17/05/25 14:41:38 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
17/05/25 14:41:38 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
17/05/25 14:41:38 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(hadoop); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(hadoop); groups with modify permissions: Set()
17/05/25 14:41:38 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 37132.
17/05/25 14:41:38 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
17/05/25 14:41:38 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
17/05/25 14:41:38 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Using org.apache.spark.storage.DefaultTopologyMapper for getting topology information
17/05/25 14:41:38 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: BlockManagerMasterEndpoint up
17/05/25 14:41:38 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /mnt/tmp/blockmgr-e368a261-c1a1-49e7-8533-8081896a45e4
17/05/25 14:41:38 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 4.0 GB
17/05/25 14:41:38 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
17/05/25 14:41:39 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
17/05/25 14:41:39 INFO SparkUI: Bound SparkUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://10.185.53.161:4040
17/05/25 14:41:39 INFO Utils: Using initial executors = 12, max of spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors, spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors and spark.executor.instances
17/05/25 14:41:39 INFO RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at ip-10-185-53-161.eu-west-1.compute.internal/10.185.53.161:8032
17/05/25 14:41:39 INFO Client: Requesting a new application from cluster with 5 NodeManagers
17/05/25 14:41:40 INFO Client: Verifying our application has not requested more than the maximum memory capability of the cluster (11520 MB per container)
17/05/25 14:41:40 INFO Client: Will allocate AM container, with 896 MB memory including 384 MB overhead
17/05/25 14:41:40 INFO Client: Setting up container launch context for our AM
17/05/25 14:41:40 INFO Client: Setting up the launch environment for our AM container
17/05/25 14:41:40 INFO Client: Preparing resources for our AM container
17/05/25 14:41:40 WARN Client: Neither spark.yarn.jars nor spark.yarn.archive is set, falling back to uploading libraries under SPARK_HOME.
17/05/25 14:41:42 INFO Client: Uploading resource file:/mnt/tmp/spark-4f534fa1-c377-4113-9c86-96d5cdab4cb5/__spark_libs__6500399427935716229.zip -> hdfs://ip-10-185-53-161.eu-west-1.compute.internal:8020/user/hadoop/.sparkStaging/application_1495720658394_0004/__spark_libs__6500399427935716229.zip
17/05/25 14:41:43 INFO Client: Uploading resource file:/home/hadoop/RedshiftJDBC42-1.2.1.1001.jar -> hdfs://ip-10-185-53-161.eu-west-1.compute.internal:8020/user/hadoop/.sparkStaging/application_1495720658394_0004/RedshiftJDBC42-1.2.1.1001.jar
17/05/25 14:41:43 INFO Client: Uploading resource file:/home/hadoop/.ivy2/jars/com.databricks_spark-avro_2.11-3.2.0.jar -> hdfs://ip-10-185-53-161.eu-west-1.compute.internal:8020/user/hadoop/.sparkStaging/application_1495720658394_0004/com.databricks_spark-avro_2.11-3.2.0.jar
17/05/25 14:41:43 INFO Client: Uploading resource file:/home/hadoop/.ivy2/jars/org.slf4j_slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar -> hdfs://ip-10-185-53-161.eu-west-1.compute.internal:8020/user/hadoop/.sparkStaging/application_1495720658394_0004/org.slf4j_slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar
17/05/25 14:41:43 INFO Client: Uploading resource file:/home/hadoop/.ivy2/jars/org.apache.avro_avro-1.7.6.jar -> hdfs://ip-10-185-53-161.eu-west-1.compute.internal:8020/user/hadoop/.sparkStaging/application_1495720658394_0004/org.apache.avro_avro-1.7.6.jar
17/05/25 14:41:43 INFO Client: Uploading resource file:/home/hadoop/.ivy2/jars/org.codehaus.jackson_jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar -> hdfs://ip-10-185-53-161.eu-west-1.compute.internal:8020/user/hadoop/.sparkStaging/application_1495720658394_0004/org.codehaus.jackson_jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar
17/05/25 14:41:43 INFO Client: Uploading resource file:/home/hadoop/.ivy2/jars/org.codehaus.jackson_jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar -> hdfs://ip-10-185-53-161.eu-west-1.compute.internal:8020/user/hadoop/.sparkStaging/application_1495720658394_0004/org.codehaus.jackson_jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar
17/05/25 14:41:43 INFO Client: Uploading resource file:/home/hadoop/.ivy2/jars/com.thoughtworks.paranamer_paranamer-2.3.jar -> hdfs://ip-10-185-53-161.eu-west-1.compute.internal:8020/user/hadoop/.sparkStaging/application_1495720658394_0004/com.thoughtworks.paranamer_paranamer-2.3.jar
17/05/25 14:41:43 INFO Client: Uploading resource file:/home/hadoop/.ivy2/jars/org.xerial.snappy_snappy-java-1.0.5.jar -> hdfs://ip-10-185-53-161.eu-west-1.compute.internal:8020/user/hadoop/.sparkStaging/application_1495720658394_0004/org.xerial.snappy_snappy-java-1.0.5.jar
17/05/25 14:41:43 INFO Client: Uploading resource file:/home/hadoop/.ivy2/jars/org.apache.commons_commons-compress-1.4.1.jar -> hdfs://ip-10-185-53-161.eu-west-1.compute.internal:8020/user/hadoop/.sparkStaging/application_1495720658394_0004/org.apache.commons_commons-compress-1.4.1.jar
17/05/25 14:41:43 INFO Client: Uploading resource file:/home/hadoop/.ivy2/jars/org.tukaani_xz-1.0.jar -> hdfs://ip-10-185-53-161.eu-west-1.compute.internal:8020/user/hadoop/.sparkStaging/application_1495720658394_0004/org.tukaani_xz-1.0.jar
17/05/25 14:41:43 INFO Client: Uploading resource file:/etc/spark/conf/hive-site.xml -> hdfs://ip-10-185-53-161.eu-west-1.compute.internal:8020/user/hadoop/.sparkStaging/application_1495720658394_0004/hive-site.xml
17/05/25 14:41:43 INFO Client: Uploading resource file:/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip -> hdfs://ip-10-185-53-161.eu-west-1.compute.internal:8020/user/hadoop/.sparkStaging/application_1495720658394_0004/pyspark.zip
17/05/25 14:41:43 INFO Client: Uploading resource file:/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip -> hdfs://ip-10-185-53-161.eu-west-1.compute.internal:8020/user/hadoop/.sparkStaging/application_1495720658394_0004/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip
17/05/25 14:41:43 INFO Client: Uploading resource file:/home/hadoop/dependencies.zip -> hdfs://ip-10-185-53-161.eu-west-1.compute.internal:8020/user/hadoop/.sparkStaging/application_1495720658394_0004/dependencies.zip
17/05/25 14:41:43 WARN Client: Same path resource file:/home/hadoop/.ivy2/jars/com.databricks_spark-avro_2.11-3.2.0.jar added multiple times to distributed cache.
17/05/25 14:41:43 WARN Client: Same path resource file:/home/hadoop/.ivy2/jars/org.slf4j_slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar added multiple times to distributed cache.
17/05/25 14:41:43 WARN Client: Same path resource file:/home/hadoop/.ivy2/jars/org.apache.avro_avro-1.7.6.jar added multiple times to distributed cache.
17/05/25 14:41:43 WARN Client: Same path resource file:/home/hadoop/.ivy2/jars/org.codehaus.jackson_jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar added multiple times to distributed cache.
17/05/25 14:41:43 WARN Client: Same path resource file:/home/hadoop/.ivy2/jars/org.codehaus.jackson_jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar added multiple times to distributed cache.
17/05/25 14:41:43 WARN Client: Same path resource file:/home/hadoop/.ivy2/jars/com.thoughtworks.paranamer_paranamer-2.3.jar added multiple times to distributed cache.
17/05/25 14:41:43 WARN Client: Same path resource file:/home/hadoop/.ivy2/jars/org.xerial.snappy_snappy-java-1.0.5.jar added multiple times to distributed cache.
17/05/25 14:41:43 WARN Client: Same path resource file:/home/hadoop/.ivy2/jars/org.apache.commons_commons-compress-1.4.1.jar added multiple times to distributed cache.
17/05/25 14:41:43 WARN Client: Same path resource file:/home/hadoop/.ivy2/jars/org.tukaani_xz-1.0.jar added multiple times to distributed cache.
17/05/25 14:41:43 INFO Client: Uploading resource file:/mnt/tmp/spark-4f534fa1-c377-4113-9c86-96d5cdab4cb5/__spark_conf__1516567354161750682.zip -> hdfs://ip-10-185-53-161.eu-west-1.compute.internal:8020/user/hadoop/.sparkStaging/application_1495720658394_0004/__spark_conf__.zip
17/05/25 14:41:43 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: hadoop
17/05/25 14:41:43 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: hadoop
17/05/25 14:41:43 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
17/05/25 14:41:43 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
17/05/25 14:41:43 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(hadoop); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(hadoop); groups with modify permissions: Set()
17/05/25 14:41:43 INFO Client: Submitting application application_1495720658394_0004 to ResourceManager
17/05/25 14:41:43 INFO YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1495720658394_0004
17/05/25 14:41:43 INFO SchedulerExtensionServices: Starting Yarn extension services with app application_1495720658394_0004 and attemptId None
17/05/25 14:41:44 INFO Client: Application report for application_1495720658394_0004 (state: ACCEPTED)
17/05/25 14:41:44 INFO Client: 
     client token: N/A
     diagnostics: N/A
     ApplicationMaster host: N/A
     ApplicationMaster RPC port: -1
     queue: default
     start time: 1495723303463
     final status: UNDEFINED
     tracking URL: http://ip-10-185-53-161.eu-west-1.compute.internal:20888/proxy/application_1495720658394_0004/
     user: hadoop
17/05/25 14:41:45 INFO Client: Application report for application_1495720658394_0004 (state: ACCEPTED)
17/05/25 14:41:46 INFO YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnSchedulerEndpoint: ApplicationMaster registered as NettyRpcEndpointRef(null)
17/05/25 14:41:46 INFO Client: Application report for application_1495720658394_0004 (state: ACCEPTED)
17/05/25 14:41:46 INFO YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Add WebUI Filter. org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter, Map(PROXY_HOSTS -> ip-10-185-53-161.eu-west-1.compute.internal, PROXY_URI_BASES -> http://ip-10-185-53-161.eu-west-1.compute.internal:20888/proxy/application_1495720658394_0004), /proxy/application_1495720658394_0004
17/05/25 14:41:46 INFO JettyUtils: Adding filter: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter
17/05/25 14:41:47 INFO Client: Application report for application_1495720658394_0004 (state: RUNNING)
17/05/25 14:41:47 INFO Client: 
     client token: N/A
     diagnostics: N/A
     ApplicationMaster host: 10.185.52.31
     ApplicationMaster RPC port: 0
     queue: default
     start time: 1495723303463
     final status: UNDEFINED
     tracking URL: http://ip-10-185-53-161.eu-west-1.compute.internal:20888/proxy/application_1495720658394_0004/
     user: hadoop
17/05/25 14:41:47 INFO YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Application application_1495720658394_0004 has started running.
17/05/25 14:41:47 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 37860.
17/05/25 14:41:47 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 10.185.53.161:37860
17/05/25 14:41:47 INFO BlockManager: Using org.apache.spark.storage.RandomBlockReplicationPolicy for block replication policy
17/05/25 14:41:47 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registering BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 10.185.53.161, 37860, None)
17/05/25 14:41:47 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager 10.185.53.161:37860 with 4.0 GB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, 10.185.53.161, 37860, None)
17/05/25 14:41:47 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 10.185.53.161, 37860, None)
17/05/25 14:41:47 INFO BlockManager: external shuffle service port = 7337
17/05/25 14:41:47 INFO BlockManager: Initialized BlockManager: BlockManagerId(driver, 10.185.53.161, 37860, None)
17/05/25 14:41:47 INFO EventLoggingListener: Logging events to hdfs:///var/log/spark/apps/application_1495720658394_0004
17/05/25 14:41:47 INFO Utils: Using initial executors = 12, max of spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors, spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors and spark.executor.instances
17/05/25 14:41:50 INFO YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnDriverEndpoint: Registered executor NettyRpcEndpointRef(null) (10.185.52.31:57406) with ID 5
17/05/25 14:41:50 INFO ExecutorAllocationManager: New executor 5 has registered (new total is 1)
17/05/25 14:41:50 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager ip-10-185-52-31.eu-west-1.compute.internal:38781 with 4.0 GB RAM, BlockManagerId(5, ip-10-185-52-31.eu-west-1.compute.internal, 38781, None)
17/05/25 14:41:50 INFO YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnDriverEndpoint: Registered executor NettyRpcEndpointRef(null) (10.185.53.45:40096) with ID 3
17/05/25 14:41:50 INFO ExecutorAllocationManager: New executor 3 has registered (new total is 2)
17/05/25 14:41:50 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager ip-10-185-53-45.eu-west-1.compute.internal:43702 with 4.0 GB RAM, BlockManagerId(3, ip-10-185-53-45.eu-west-1.compute.internal, 43702, None)
17/05/25 14:41:50 INFO YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnDriverEndpoint: Registered executor NettyRpcEndpointRef(null) (10.185.53.135:42390) with ID 2
17/05/25 14:41:50 INFO ExecutorAllocationManager: New executor 2 has registered (new total is 3)
17/05/25 14:41:50 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager ip-10-185-53-135.eu-west-1.compute.internal:41552 with 4.0 GB RAM, BlockManagerId(2, ip-10-185-53-135.eu-west-1.compute.internal, 41552, None)
17/05/25 14:41:50 INFO YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnDriverEndpoint: Registered executor NettyRpcEndpointRef(null) (10.185.53.10:60612) with ID 1
17/05/25 14:41:50 INFO ExecutorAllocationManager: New executor 1 has registered (new total is 4)
17/05/25 14:41:50 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager ip-10-185-53-10.eu-west-1.compute.internal:33391 with 4.0 GB RAM, BlockManagerId(1, ip-10-185-53-10.eu-west-1.compute.internal, 33391, None)
17/05/25 14:41:50 INFO YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnDriverEndpoint: Registered executor NettyRpcEndpointRef(null) (10.185.53.68:57424) with ID 4
17/05/25 14:41:50 INFO ExecutorAllocationManager: New executor 4 has registered (new total is 5)
17/05/25 14:41:50 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager ip-10-185-53-68.eu-west-1.compute.internal:34222 with 4.0 GB RAM, BlockManagerId(4, ip-10-185-53-68.eu-west-1.compute.internal, 34222, None)
17/05/25 14:42:09 INFO YarnClientSchedulerBackend: SchedulerBackend is ready for scheduling beginning after waiting maxRegisteredResourcesWaitingTime: 30000(ms)
17/05/25 14:42:09 INFO SharedState: Warehouse path is 'hdfs:///user/spark/warehouse'.
17/05/25 14:42:10 WARN Utils: Truncated the string representation of a plan since it was too large. This behavior can be adjusted by setting 'spark.debug.maxToStringFields' in SparkEnv.conf.
17/05/25 14:42:11 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 170.416763 ms
17/05/25 14:42:11 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: collect at /home/hadoop/iface_extractions/select_fields.py:90
17/05/25 14:42:11 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 0 (collect at /home/hadoop/iface_extractions/select_fields.py:90) with 1 output partitions
17/05/25 14:42:11 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 0 (collect at /home/hadoop/iface_extractions/select_fields.py:90)
17/05/25 14:42:11 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
17/05/25 14:42:11 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
17/05/25 14:42:11 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[2] at collect at /home/hadoop/iface_extractions/select_fields.py:90), which has no missing parents
17/05/25 14:42:11 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0 stored as values in memory (estimated size 7.5 KB, free 4.0 GB)
17/05/25 14:42:11 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 4.1 KB, free 4.0 GB)
17/05/25 14:42:11 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on 10.185.53.161:37860 (size: 4.1 KB, free: 4.0 GB)
17/05/25 14:42:11 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 0 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:996
17/05/25 14:42:11 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 1 missing tasks from ResultStage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[2] at collect at /home/hadoop/iface_extractions/select_fields.py:90)
17/05/25 14:42:11 INFO YarnScheduler: Adding task set 0.0 with 1 tasks
17/05/25 14:42:11 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, ip-10-185-53-135.eu-west-1.compute.internal, executor 2, partition 0, PROCESS_LOCAL, 5899 bytes)
17/05/25 14:42:11 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on ip-10-185-53-135.eu-west-1.compute.internal:41552 (size: 4.1 KB, free: 4.0 GB)
17/05/25 14:42:12 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) in 1101 ms on ip-10-185-53-135.eu-west-1.compute.internal (executor 2) (1/1)
17/05/25 14:42:12 INFO YarnScheduler: Removed TaskSet 0.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
17/05/25 14:42:12 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 0 (collect at /home/hadoop/iface_extractions/select_fields.py:90) finished in 1.109 s
17/05/25 14:42:12 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 0 finished: collect at /home/hadoop/iface_extractions/select_fields.py:90, took 1.290037 s
17/05/25 14:42:12 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_0_piece0 on 10.185.53.161:37860 in memory (size: 4.1 KB, free: 4.0 GB)
17/05/25 14:42:12 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: collect at /home/hadoop/iface_extractions/select_fields.py:91
17/05/25 14:42:12 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_0_piece0 on ip-10-185-53-135.eu-west-1.compute.internal:41552 in memory (size: 4.1 KB, free: 4.0 GB)
17/05/25 14:42:12 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 1 (collect at /home/hadoop/iface_extractions/select_fields.py:91) with 1 output partitions
17/05/25 14:42:12 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 1 (collect at /home/hadoop/iface_extractions/select_fields.py:91)
17/05/25 14:42:12 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
17/05/25 14:42:12 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
17/05/25 14:42:12 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 1 (MapPartitionsRDD[5] at collect at /home/hadoop/iface_extractions/select_fields.py:91), which has no missing parents
17/05/25 14:42:12 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1 stored as values in memory (estimated size 7.5 KB, free 4.0 GB)
17/05/25 14:42:12 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 4.1 KB, free 4.0 GB)
17/05/25 14:42:12 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_1_piece0 in memory on 10.185.53.161:37860 (size: 4.1 KB, free: 4.0 GB)
17/05/25 14:42:12 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 1 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:996
17/05/25 14:42:12 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 1 missing tasks from ResultStage 1 (MapPartitionsRDD[5] at collect at /home/hadoop/iface_extractions/select_fields.py:91)
17/05/25 14:42:12 INFO YarnScheduler: Adding task set 1.0 with 1 tasks
17/05/25 14:42:12 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1, ip-10-185-53-68.eu-west-1.compute.internal, executor 4, partition 0, PROCESS_LOCAL, 5900 bytes)
17/05/25 14:42:13 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_1_piece0 in memory on ip-10-185-53-68.eu-west-1.compute.internal:34222 (size: 4.1 KB, free: 4.0 GB)
17/05/25 14:42:14 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1) in 1047 ms on ip-10-185-53-68.eu-west-1.compute.internal (executor 4) (1/1)
17/05/25 14:42:14 INFO YarnScheduler: Removed TaskSet 1.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
17/05/25 14:42:14 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 1 (collect at /home/hadoop/iface_extractions/select_fields.py:91) finished in 1.047 s
17/05/25 14:42:14 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 1 finished: collect at /home/hadoop/iface_extractions/select_fields.py:91, took 1.054768 s
17/05/25 14:42:14 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 13.109425 ms
17/05/25 14:42:14 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 12.568665 ms
17/05/25 14:42:14 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 11.257538 ms
17/05/25 14:42:14 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_1_piece0 on 10.185.53.161:37860 in memory (size: 4.1 KB, free: 4.0 GB)
17/05/25 14:42:14 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_1_piece0 on ip-10-185-53-68.eu-west-1.compute.internal:34222 in memory (size: 4.1 KB, free: 4.0 GB)
17/05/25 14:42:14 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 11.563958 ms
17/05/25 14:42:14 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 18.189301 ms
17/05/25 14:42:14 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 13.490762 ms
17/05/25 14:42:14 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 15.156166 ms
17/05/25 14:42:50 INFO ExecutorAllocationManager: Request to remove executorIds: 5, 3
17/05/25 14:42:50 INFO YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Requesting to kill executor(s) 5, 3
17/05/25 14:42:50 INFO YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Actual list of executor(s) to be killed is 5, 3
17/05/25 14:42:50 INFO ExecutorAllocationManager: Removing executor 5 because it has been idle for 60 seconds (new desired total will be 4)
17/05/25 14:42:50 INFO ExecutorAllocationManager: Removing executor 3 because it has been idle for 60 seconds (new desired total will be 3)
17/05/25 14:42:50 INFO ExecutorAllocationManager: Request to remove executorIds: 1
17/05/25 14:42:50 INFO YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Requesting to kill executor(s) 1
17/05/25 14:42:50 INFO YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Actual list of executor(s) to be killed is 1
17/05/25 14:42:50 INFO ExecutorAllocationManager: Removing executor 1 because it has been idle for 60 seconds (new desired total will be 2)
17/05/25 14:42:50 INFO YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnDriverEndpoint: Disabling executor 5.
17/05/25 14:42:50 INFO DAGScheduler: Executor lost: 5 (epoch 0)
17/05/25 14:42:50 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Trying to remove executor 5 from BlockManagerMaster.
17/05/25 14:42:50 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Removing block manager BlockManagerId(5, ip-10-185-52-31.eu-west-1.compute.internal, 38781, None)
17/05/25 14:42:50 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Removed 5 successfully in removeExecutor
17/05/25 14:42:50 INFO YarnScheduler: Executor 5 on ip-10-185-52-31.eu-west-1.compute.internal killed by driver.
17/05/25 14:42:50 INFO ExecutorAllocationManager: Existing executor 5 has been removed (new total is 4)
17/05/25 14:42:51 INFO YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnDriverEndpoint: Disabling executor 1.
17/05/25 14:42:51 INFO DAGScheduler: Executor lost: 1 (epoch 0)
17/05/25 14:42:51 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Trying to remove executor 1 from BlockManagerMaster.
17/05/25 14:42:51 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Removing block manager BlockManagerId(1, ip-10-185-53-10.eu-west-1.compute.internal, 33391, None)
17/05/25 14:42:51 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Removed 1 successfully in removeExecutor
17/05/25 14:42:51 INFO YarnScheduler: Executor 1 on ip-10-185-53-10.eu-west-1.compute.internal killed by driver.
17/05/25 14:42:51 INFO ExecutorAllocationManager: Existing executor 1 has been removed (new total is 3)
17/05/25 14:42:51 INFO YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnDriverEndpoint: Disabling executor 3.
17/05/25 14:42:51 INFO DAGScheduler: Executor lost: 3 (epoch 0)
17/05/25 14:42:51 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Trying to remove executor 3 from BlockManagerMaster.
17/05/25 14:42:51 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Removing block manager BlockManagerId(3, ip-10-185-53-45.eu-west-1.compute.internal, 43702, None)
17/05/25 14:42:51 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Removed 3 successfully in removeExecutor
17/05/25 14:42:51 INFO YarnScheduler: Executor 3 on ip-10-185-53-45.eu-west-1.compute.internal killed by driver.
17/05/25 14:42:51 INFO ExecutorAllocationManager: Existing executor 3 has been removed (new total is 2)
17/05/25 14:43:12 INFO ExecutorAllocationManager: Request to remove executorIds: 2
17/05/25 14:43:12 INFO YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Requesting to kill executor(s) 2
17/05/25 14:43:12 INFO YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Actual list of executor(s) to be killed is 2
17/05/25 14:43:12 INFO ExecutorAllocationManager: Removing executor 2 because it has been idle for 60 seconds (new desired total will be 1)
17/05/25 14:43:13 INFO YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnDriverEndpoint: Disabling executor 2.
17/05/25 14:43:13 INFO DAGScheduler: Executor lost: 2 (epoch 0)
17/05/25 14:43:13 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Trying to remove executor 2 from BlockManagerMaster.
17/05/25 14:43:13 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Removing block manager BlockManagerId(2, ip-10-185-53-135.eu-west-1.compute.internal, 41552, None)
17/05/25 14:43:13 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Removed 2 successfully in removeExecutor
17/05/25 14:43:13 INFO YarnScheduler: Executor 2 on ip-10-185-53-135.eu-west-1.compute.internal killed by driver.
17/05/25 14:43:13 INFO ExecutorAllocationManager: Existing executor 2 has been removed (new total is 1)
17/05/25 14:43:14 INFO ExecutorAllocationManager: Request to remove executorIds: 4
17/05/25 14:43:14 INFO YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Requesting to kill executor(s) 4
17/05/25 14:43:14 INFO YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Actual list of executor(s) to be killed is 4
17/05/25 14:43:14 INFO ExecutorAllocationManager: Removing executor 4 because it has been idle for 60 seconds (new desired total will be 0)
17/05/25 14:43:17 INFO YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnDriverEndpoint: Disabling executor 4.
17/05/25 14:43:17 INFO DAGScheduler: Executor lost: 4 (epoch 0)
17/05/25 14:43:17 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Trying to remove executor 4 from BlockManagerMaster.
17/05/25 14:43:17 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Removing block manager BlockManagerId(4, ip-10-185-53-68.eu-west-1.compute.internal, 34222, None)
17/05/25 14:43:17 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Removed 4 successfully in removeExecutor
17/05/25 14:43:17 INFO YarnScheduler: Executor 4 on ip-10-185-53-68.eu-west-1.compute.internal killed by driver.
17/05/25 14:43:17 INFO ExecutorAllocationManager: Existing executor 4 has been removed (new total is 0)
```

Comment: Why don't you inspect the YARN logs for `application_1495720658394_0004`? There you will find out what happened to each and every executor, plus their AppMaster *(which has container _00001)*.

Answer (score 12):

My *guess* is that you've got [Dynamic Resource Allocation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html#dynamic-resource-allocation) enabled in your Spark configuration.

> Spark provides a mechanism to dynamically adjust the resources your application occupies based on the workload. This means that your application may give resources back to the cluster if they are no longer used and request them again later when there is demand. This feature is particularly useful if multiple applications share resources in your Spark cluster.
>
> **This feature is disabled by default** and available on all coarse-grained cluster managers, i.e. standalone mode, YARN mode, and Mesos coarse-grained mode.

I highlighted the relevant part that says it is disabled by default and hence I can only guess that it was enabled.

From [ExecutorAllocationManager](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ExecutorAllocationManager.scala):

> An agent that dynamically allocates and removes executors based on the workload.

With that said, I'd use web UI and see if [spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html#configuration-and-setup) property is enabled or not.

> There are two requirements for using this feature (Dynamic Resource Allocation). First, your application must set `spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled` to `true`. Second, you must set up an external shuffle service on each worker node in the same cluster and set `spark.shuffle.service.enabled` to `true` in your application.

This is the [line](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ExecutorAllocationManager.scala#L406) that prints out the INFO message:

```
logInfo("Request to remove executorIds: " + executors.mkString(", "))
```

---

You can also kill executors using [SparkContext.killExecutors](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.SparkContext@killExecutors(executorIds:Seq%5BString%5D):Boolean) that gives a Spark developer a way to kill executors himself.

> **killExecutors(executorIds: Seq[String]): Boolean** Request that the cluster manager kill the specified executors.

There are two `killExecutors` actually and they are very helpful for demo purposes as you can easily show how executors come and go.

Comment: But the command line shown in the question contains `--num-executors 12` and that should take precedence over whatever is defined in `spark-defaults.conf`...

Comment: I remember some discussion about this and a change that accepted `--num-executors` (that previously used to disable dynamic allocation). Unless I'm mistaken, the code for YARN is in [YarnSparkHadoopUtil](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/resource-managers/yarn/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/yarn/YarnSparkHadoopUtil.scala#L270)

Comment: Excellent. Now I have another proof that on each and every Spark upgrade, you've got to review the source code -- top to bottom -- to discover what has changed, both in the documented and the undocumented features => #JobSecurity

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have Dynamic Allocation, you can also set the "Idle Timeout" and the minimum number of executors that are alive after that Idle Timeout