# spark-submit runs infinitely - displayed errors: Removal of executor n requested - Asked to remove non-existent executor n+1

Tags: apache-spark

I have deployed a spark standalone cluster with one driver and 2 executors, each one running on a separate machine.

Whenever I submit a job to the master using `spark-submit --master spark://driver_ip:7077 example/src/main/python/pi.py`, It runs infinitely and displays these errors:

```
 BlockManagerMaster:54 - Removal of executor 50 requested
 CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint:54 - Asked to remove non-existent executor 50
 BlockManagerMasterEndpoint:54 - Trying to remove executor 50 from BlockManagerMaster.
 StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint:54 - Executor updated: app-20181129123913-0003/52 is now RUNNING
 StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint:54 - Executor updated: app-20181129123913-0003/51 is now EXITED (Command exited with code 1)
 StandaloneSchedulerBackend:54 - Executor app-20181129123913-0003/51 removed: Command exited with code 1
 StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint:54 - Executor added: app-20181129123913-0003/53 on worker-20181129120029-10.0.1.101-36599 (10.0.1.101:36599) with 1 core(s)
```

Each time the number in `Removal of executor` increments and the program doesn't end. It looks like the executors are constantly refusing the jobs.

Could anyone help me figure out the issue.

Note that I can see that the Spark executors are registered with the Driver In the Spark Manager's web UI.

Comment: Are you sure that executors can be reached from the machine where you start driver?

Comment: Yes because in the spark's manager web UI, there is the information that the tasks are running on both executors, but the problem is that they keep running infinitely.

Comment: Please check if Dynamic Allocation is enabled, the explanation for this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44185513/8085047

Comment: @LakshmanBattini thank's for your help. I'm still getting the same error after adding this to the configuration

Comment: @AyoubOm Spark dynamic allocation needs to be disabled. I suspect the issue is because it is enabled.