# Spark executors getting idle timeout

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, bigdata, amazon-emr

I have an EMR cluster where I am running pyspark jobs with spark dynamic allocation.

spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true

Below is config of cluster

```
1 Node
128GB Ram
10 cores

Core Nodes
Autoscaled till 10 nodes
Each with
128 GB Ram
10 Cores
```

When I submit a job, at the start of the job, there are almost 100 executors getting created and then almost 95 of them get killed by master after an idle timeout of 3 minutes.

My question is if most of the executors were not being used and only 5 were needed, why spark created additional 95 executors?

As per my understanding, in dynamic mode, spark should create only the required number of executors.

Below is screenshot from history server about how the executors are getting killed.

Please note that I am not facing any OOM issues. The executors were killed because of idle timeout.
[image: The picture showing killed executors]

Answer (score 0):

This is related to the question and answer here: [Why would Spark executors be removed (with "ExecutorAllocationManager: Request to remove executorIds" in the logs)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44183527/why-would-spark-executors-be-removed-with-executorallocationmanager-request-t)

Throughout the lifetime of your job, different stages have different level of compute intensity. I am guessing that the behavior you are seeing happens because you have a job that starts with a large amount of data but the end output is something smaller. In our team, we have quite a few such jobs - start with tens of TB of data, but the output is couple of MB, with most reductions happening via various applications of groupBy() and summary statistic functions. So the final stages of the job have shuffle input of hundreds of MB, but the initial stage has input of tens of TB. So, since you have `spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true`, Spark creates lot of executors to handle the load of the initial stages of your job, but then releases them when it is optimal to use much fewer for the later stages of your job.